# Prove if a graph has an odd number of vertices and is regular of degree d then d must be even

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

I try to prove by lemma that is 
If G is regular of degree d  then

$e=\frac{dv}{2}$

I tried to prove by divided in to two case by e is odd and e is even

**Case 1** Suppose $e$ is odd

then $e=2n+1$,  $v=2n+1$

put in to formula

$2n+1=d\frac{(2n+1)}{2}$

$\frac{(2n+1)}{(2n+1)}=\frac{d}{2}$

$1=\frac{d}{2}$

$2=d$

then degree is even

but I stuck at **case 2** if $e$ is even because
$e=2n$

$2n=\frac{d(2n+1)}{2}$

$\frac{4n}{2n+1}=d$

but stuck at this because  I divide $4n$ by $2n+1$ it has remainder and it can't proof degree must be even

anyone can recommend the way to proof this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The degree sum formula implies that
$$
d\times n(G)=\sum_{v\in V}\text{deg}(v)=2e(G)
$$
where $e(G)$ is the number of edges in $G$ and $n(G)$ is the number of vertices in $G$. Now consider the parity of both sides If $d$ is odd and $n$ is odd what is  the problem?